# How to count not nulls in a mongo subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("570ee4687db3df6a23c085"),
    "rep" : ObjectId("570beb"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-04-14T00:29:28.998Z"),
    "data" : {
            "country" : "",
            "age" : 1,
            "age_unit" : "days",
            "id" : "990121124"
    },
    "label" : "p_list"
```

I want a query of the number of elements of "data" for which the value is NOT NULL. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by *number of elements of "data" for which the value is NOT NULL.*?

Comment: The query of this document should return a value of  3, because 'data.country' is NULL.

Comment: `data.country' ` is actually not `NULL` but empty string. I think `mapReduce` is your best bet here.